# Why is my DQN-agent's training so inefficient?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn, tf-agent

I am trying to train an agent to play tic-tac-toe perfectly as a second player (the first player walks randomly) with the DQN-agent from tf-agents, but my training is extremely slow.

[For 100_000 steps, the model did not improve its results in any way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvNvE.png)

I understand that the model should not be trained in 100 000 steps, but during this period, some results should definitely have appeared.

To be honest, I don't fully understand what's wrong with my learning code...

```
LOG_PERIOD = 1000
PRINT_PERIOD = 100
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
NUM_ITERATIONS = 100_000
 
graph = Graphic(LOG_PERIOD)
tf_env = TFPyEnvironment(RandomTicTacToeEnvironment())
 
q_net = QNetwork(
    tf_env.observation_spec(),
    tf_env.action_spec(),
    fc_layer_params=(100,)
)
 
train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)
 
agent = DqnAgent(
    time_step_spec=tf_env.time_step_spec(),
    action_spec=tf_env.action_spec(),
    q_network=q_net,
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    epsilon_greedy=0.1,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter
)
agent.initialize()
 
eval_policy = agent.policy
collect_policy = agent.collect_policy

replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,
    batch_size=tf_env.batch_size,
    max_length=1000
)
 
collect_driver = dynamic_step_driver.DynamicStepDriver(
    tf_env,
    collect_policy,
    observers=[replay_buffer.add_batch],
    num_steps=10
)
 
collect_driver.run = common.function(collect_driver.run)
agent.train = common.function(agent.train)
 
initial_collect_policy = random_tf_policy.RandomTFPolicy(
    tf_env.time_step_spec(),
    tf_env.action_spec()
)
 
dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
    num_parallel_calls=3,
    sample_batch_size=8,
    num_steps=2,
    single_deterministic_pass=False
).prefetch(3)
     
iterator = iter(dataset)
 
dynamic_step_driver.DynamicStepDriver(
    tf_env,
    initial_collect_policy,
    observers=[replay_buffer.add_batch],
    num_steps=10
)
 
time_step = tf_env.reset()

for _ in np.arange(NUM_ITERATIONS+1):
    time_step, _ = collect_driver.run(time_step)
    experience, _ = next(iterator)
 
    step = agent.train_step_counter.numpy()
    train_loss = agent.train(experience).loss

    if step % PRINT_PERIOD == 0:
        print('step = {0}: loss = {1}'.format(step, train_loss))
 
    for reward in tf.reshape(experience.reward, [-1]):
        graph.check(step, reward)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Full project with code of env: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1myp2aRAd03PP2RoPq1L9rxuaxHcnJf_U?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's your epsilon value. Not saying it's the only problem.

1. First of all don't fixate yourself to the 100000 steps, it could definitely train in less than that, especially in such a finite space.
2. Introduce a better optimal epsilon that decays much more slowly and see what happens. Test with a range of values and see if your learning gets better and steps are reduced.
3. Try breaking down that DQN built-in function yourself and see what more hyperparameters you might tweak to fit your problem.